# Where to buy a prepaid SIM card at Grenoble airport or Alpe d'Huez?

Tags: airports, france, cellphones, grenoble

I'm going to Alpe d'Huez via bus from GNB (Alpes–Isère Airport‏).

Would I be able to buy a SIM card with about 2 GB of data at the airport?

If not, where can I buy one at Alpe d'Huez?

Comment: I'm not leaving this as an answer as I'm not certain, but I flew through Grenoble airport a few weeks ago and it was a tiny airport, I didn't notice a place to buy a SIM but I wasn't looking. I'd be surprised if one exists as there weren't many shops at the airport.

Answer (score 3):

GNB has a newsagent (RELAY) that just *might* be able to help. However it might be worth checking first, the company can be contacted via [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/relaycom).

A more promising alternative seems to be [ALPEDHUEZNET](https://www.alpedhueznet.com/internet/prepaid-european-sim-card-649100) which can be bought on line.

Answer (score 2):

As pnuts said, you should try the [RELAY at Grenoble airport](http://www.grenoble-airport.com/en/services/shops).

If there's no SIM card there, try the [bureaux de tabac](https://www.alpedhuez.com/fr/hiver/la-station/commerces/presse-tabac.html) in l'Alpe d'Huez. [You should find a SIM card there](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76670/temporary-sim-card-while-visiting-france/76888#76888).

Comment: If I understood correctly, "bureaux de tabac" only opens between 1/7-28/8 (2 months), so it's not relevant for tomorrow, right?

Comment: @EranBetzalel I'm answering a bit late but: 1/ they'll probably be closed on Sunday, regardless of the date 2/ I emailed them and the dates on the website are confusing: they actually close one month during the spring and one month during summer